# Creating a time series from table with start & end dates

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data table with two date fields and a job category field as below:

```
Start Date          End Date    Job title

07-Sep-09           30-Sep-09   Category 1

01-Oct-07           06-Nov-07   Category 1

05-Jun-09          31-Aug-09    Category 1

05-Jan-09          04-Jun-09    Category 2

08-Jan-08          08-Jan-08    Category 2

10-Jan-08          12-Jan-08    Category 2
```

The full data table is about 28,000 lines long and spans 10 years.

The data is messy. The list below has someone starting & leaving a role on 8 Jan, which probably didn’t happen but creates additional challenges. For example the number of individuals employed in each category each month would be a factor of the number of days in each month.

I’m aiming to create a number of time series that show:

•   the count for each category of job title for each month and for each year – for example the first time series

•   each job title’s monthly comparative count for example the second time series

I originally wanted to do this in excel but my laptop fell over. My excel approach was to create a table that could be used to create a time series. I did this picture from excel below.

I am at a loss on how to do this in R. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Paul could you please provide a sample of your expected output?

Comment: In particular, what should be time frequency of this time series? Daily, monthly, irregular with points at start and/or end dates?

Comment: Hi Antonis & Julius thanks for your questions. I've added some images of expected output. I'd like to create a monthly time series for the whole ten years. But I'd also want to create an annual  time series that just compared years. In addition, I'd create a monthly time series that compared categories for each month.

Comment: If it's monthly, then how should we handle cases like 08-Jan-08          08-Jan-08    Category 2? Should it be counted to Jan-08 in a way that that there was at least one day in this month?

Comment: Good thought. I'd include that as one day. So I guess part of the problem is aggregating the data. I'd start with mean per month and then look at median by month. The sample columns are real data, people frequently enter and leave the job category during month.

Comment: I guess there is an additional level of aggregation relating to the calendar months. So a count of 112 would be 4 for February, and a count of 155 would be 5 for January, March etc.